# How to write `a >>= std::countr_zero(a);` in C?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

In C++20, to remove trailing zeros in the binary representation of an integer you can use `a >>= std::countr_zero(a);`.
I think it is optimized by the compiler so very fast.

What would be the C equivalent, is there a faster way to do it than a while loop?

```
while ((a & 1) == 0) { a >> 1; }
```

Comment: probably `a >>= whatever_the_countr_zero_function_is_called_in_c(a);`

Comment: I added the C++ tag since this would be one of the few cases where it is correct to use both tags at once (when comparing the languages).

Comment: You might like [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightLinear)

Comment: It's not obvious which method that's the fastest, it depends a lot on the ISA. I showed the countr_zero, the while loop and the bit twiddling hack into Godbolt for x86 but got very different asm for all 3 cases. Curiously, the `std::countr_zero(a)` boiled down to a `rep` call in the optimized code on gcc x86.

Comment: `countr_zero` is simply a standardised version of the various intrinsics or compiler built-ins that are already available. Which compiler/CPU are you using?

Comment: What's wrong with the `while` loop? It's clear enough that optimizers should be able to recognize it.